# Taylor expansion of $\tan\sin x$

Tags: calculus

First,

$\sin x= x- {1\over6}x^3 + {1\over120}x^5 +o(x^7)$

$\tan x = x +{1\over3}x^3 +{2\over15}x^5 +o(x^7)$

So I got

$\tan \sin x= x-{1\over6}x^3+{1\over120}x^5 + o(x^7) +{1\over3}(x-{1\over6}x^3+{1\over120}x^5 +o(x^7))^3 + {2\over15}(x-{1\over6}x^3 +{1\over120}x^5 +o(x^7))^5  +o((x-{1\over6}x^3 +{1\over120}x^5 +o(x^7)^7) =$

$x+{1\over6}x^3+{31\over360}x^5 +o(x^7)$

Obviously I made a mistake somewhere  but I'm looking at it for over an hour and I can't figure out what I did wrong.

Comment: As opposed to $x+\frac16x^3-\frac{1}{40}x^5+O(x^7)$. You keep using $o$ instead of $O$.

Comment: I know what the correct answer is(I can use wolfram alpha like everybody else) and where I'm from we sometimes use this notation. I only wanted to know what did I do wrong.

Comment: I only mentioned the answer so others would know your problem is in the $x^5$ coefficient. Out of curiosity, if you use $o$ for $O$, what do you use for $o$?

Comment: We use little o for landau symbols. As for notations we often use diferent notations for same things depending on professor. Truth be told that can be confusing at times. For example correct notation would be gcd(a,b) but (a,b) is commonly used which can be number of different things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In\begin{multline}\left(x-\frac16x^3+\frac1{120}x^5\right)+\frac13\left(x-\frac16x^3+\frac1{120}x^5\right)^3+\frac2{15}\left(x-\frac16x^3+\frac1{120}x^5\right)^5=\\=\left(x-\frac16x^3+\frac1{120}x^5\right)+\frac{x^3}3\left(1-\frac16x^2+\frac1{120}x^4\right)^3+\frac{x^5}{120}\left(1-\frac16x^2+\frac1{120}x^4\right)^5,\end{multline}

- from the first term, the coefficient of $x^5$ is $\frac1{120}$ (of course);
- from the second term, the coefficient of $x^5$ is $-\frac16$;
- from the third term, the coefficient of $x^5$ is $\frac2{15}$ (of course)

and therefore globally the coefficient of $x^5$ is $\frac1{120}-\frac16+\frac2{15}=-\frac1{40}$, which is the correct coefficient.

Comment: How did you get $-{1\over6}$ in the second term?

Comment: The coefficient of $x^5$ in $\left(x-\frac16x^3+\frac1{120}x^5\right)^3$ is the coefficient of $x^2$ in $\left(1-\frac16x^2+\frac1{120}x^4\right)^3$, which is $-\frac16-\frac16-\frac16=-\frac12$. Therefore, the coefficient of $x^5$ in $\frac13\left(x-\frac16x^3+\frac1{120}x^5\right)^3$ is $-\frac16$.

Comment: Thanks, appreciate it